# Unable to run connected components on large graph

Tags: performance, neo4j, graph-algorithm, connected-components

- neo4j v 3.5
- graph-algorithms-algo v 3.5.0.1
- apoc v 3.5.0.1
- AWS R5.24xlarge: 96 vCPU & 748GB RAM with SSD

My graph is the bitcoin address graph whose degree distribution is the class power-law.

- 639,204,230 Nodes (Addresses & Transactions)
- 741,853,556 Edges (a:address)-[e:INPUT_TO]->(t:transaction)

> ```
> CALL algo.unionFind.stream(null, null, {})
> YIELD nodeId,setId
> ```

Running this from cypher-shell re-directing the output to a local file

Error & Log file is here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rzycDLkL4mVDl1Rl71xmLkZ81mSzLZIf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think the problem here might be streaming 640 millions rows of results as it looks the algorithms worked fine. Can you please report the issue to https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms as I have no experience with streaming 0.6 billion rows

Comment: @TomažBratanič thanks for your comment. Happy to open an issue, from memory I had suspected this and also tried `write: true, writeProperty:'partition'` without luck.